# How to apply date constructor to specific attribute of JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I have an x, y JSON object like this

```
var myJSON = [{x: "2021-06-29T02:00:00.000Z", y: 45.87},
    {x: "2021-06-29T03:00:00.000Z", y: 45.97},
    {x: "2021-06-29T04:00:00.000Z", y: 47.84},
    {x: "2021-06-29T05:00:00.000Z", y: 48.64}]
```

I would like to apply the date constructor to X for each entry in the array. I have also converted an array format if that is better.

```
var myArr =[["2021-06-29T02:00:00.000Z", 45.87],
  ["2021-06-29T03:00:00.000Z", 45.97],
  ["2021-06-29T04:00:00.000Z", 47.84],
  ["2021-06-29T05:00:00.000Z", 48.64]]
```

I currently get from the JSON to the array like so:

```
var myArr= myJSON.map(d => Array.from(Object.values(d)));
```

Comment: how are you currently doing that?

Comment: I thought this generalized the issue better. I can delete the other post. I currently don't have a way to do it. I get the string data from a SQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply apply `new Date(x)` when converting

```js
var myJSON = [
  { x: "2021-06-29T02:00:00.000Z", y: 45.87 },
  { x: "2021-06-29T03:00:00.000Z", y: 45.97 },
  { x: "2021-06-29T04:00:00.000Z", y: 47.84 },
  { x: "2021-06-29T05:00:00.000Z", y: 48.64 },
];

const result = myJSON.map(({ x, y }) => [new Date(x), y]);

console.log(result);
```

Note: console.log on a snippet shows the date as a string, but confirm in your browser console that it is a date